# Scripting Bitlocker Decryption of a local hard-drive

Tags: windows, security, powershell, bitlocker, vbscript

*In summary: I'm attempting to create a script that unlocks (decrypts) a hard-drive on the Windows 7 Ultimate local machine, then execute a couple of programs afterwards.*

I have a small SSD that various client cloud applications (such as Dropbox, Google Drive, etc) use. I've **decided to encrypt the drive**, but of course, the applications complain that the folder cannot be found as it is initially locked on boot. A password is required to unlock.

What I would really love to do is **manually run a script that prompts for the password** (because of course hard coding the password in script is silly), then uses that password to unlock my drive, and then start the Dropbox, et al, without complaint.

I'm fairly computer literate and have done a bit of research, but specifically, can't seem to find a way of mounting/decrypting/unlocking the drive from VBS or PowerShell (not that I mind either methodology).

Has anyone got an example of unlocking a drive with Windows-based script?

Answer (score 1):

```
manage-dbe -unlock -pw
```

The above line can be dropped into a .bat batch file and it prompts for a password to unlock a bitlocker encrypted drive.

I'm currently looking into doing this from Powershell myself, as I do want to input my password into my script as my script will be on my host OS drive which will be TrueCrypt encrypted.